# Apply Palette color to fab on pressed state

Tags: android, palette, floating-action-button

can someone give me a hint how I apply, a color generated by the Palette class, to a fab-button for the pressed state?
I am using a Listener to get the generated colors as discribed **[here](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/palette-part-2/)**, I can apply the default-state background color in the `public void setPalette(Palette palette)` action using `fab.setBackgroundColor(palette.get...())` but I don't know if there is a method to set the pressed-state background color, or if I have to use an OnClick or OnTouch Listener on the fab to set the appropriate background color on the event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey i know this is late but it might help someone

You do the below declaration of variables

```
int[][] states = new int[][] {
                        new int[] { android.R.attr.state_enabled}, // enabled
                        new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_enabled}, // disabled
                        new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_checked}, // unchecked
                        new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed}  // pressed
                };

                int[] colors = new int[] {
                        Color.RED,
                        Color.BLUE,
                        Color.GREEN,
                        Color.YELLOW
                };

(Button) btn = (Button)  findViewById(R.id.fab).setBackgroundTintList(new ColorStateList(states, colors));
```

And your are all done, i spend a ton of time looking for this. hope it helps someone.